# How to add Better dungeons to Feed the Beast

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I copy and pasted the Better Dungeon mod into the minecraft folder, seems I am doing this horribly wrong since Minecraft crashes. Here is the crash report:

```
## ---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// This doesn't make any sense!

Time: 4/7/13 2:07 PM
Description: Failed to start game

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Slot 250 is already occupied by forestry.apiculture.gadgets.BlockBeehives@1a37a86e when adding chocolate.mods.BD.BlockMobSpawner@70aa8b52
    at amq.<init>(Block.java:326)
    at akb.<init>(BlockContainer.java:11)
    at chocolate.mods.BD.BlockMobSpawner.<init>(BlockMobSpawner.java:15)
    at chocolate.mods.BD.BetterDungeons.registerBlocks(BetterDungeons.java:353)
    at chocolate.mods.BD.BetterDungeons.load(BetterDungeons.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.FMLModContainer.handleModStateEvent(FMLModContainer.java:487)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventHandler.handleEvent(EventHandler.java:69)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.SynchronizedEventHandler.handleEvent(SynchronizedEventHandler.java:45)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatch(EventBus.java:317)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatchQueuedEvents(EventBus.java:300)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:268)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.LoadController.propogateStateMessage(LoadController.java:153)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventHandler.handleEvent(EventHandler.java:69)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.SynchronizedEventHandler.handleEvent(SynchronizedEventHandler.java:45)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatch(EventBus.java:317)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatchQueuedEvents(EventBus.java:300)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:268)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.LoadController.distributeStateMessage(LoadController.java:86)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.Loader.initializeMods(Loader.java:676)
    at cpw.mods.fml.client.FMLClientHandler.finishMinecraftLoading(FMLClientHandler.java:207)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.a(Minecraft.java:458)
    at asq.a(SourceFile:56)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:746)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.4.7
    Operating System: Windows 7 (amd64) version 6.1
    Java Version: 1.7.0_06, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 75871136 bytes (72 MB) / 292892672 bytes (279 MB) up to 3956801536 bytes (3773 MB)
    Mod Pack: CWW256 forgot to change this.
    LiteLoader Mods: 5 loaded mod(s)
          - VoxelPacket version 2.0.2
          - VoxelPlayer version 0.9.6
          - Integrated Sound Packs version 1.1.1
          - VoxelMenu version 1.4.7_05
          - VoxelMap version 1.0.0
    JVM Flags: 7 total; -Xms256M -Xmx3840M -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:+AggressiveOpts -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=128m
    AABB Pool Size: 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) allocated, 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) used
    Suspicious classes: FML and Forge are installed
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
    FML: MCP v7.26a FML v4.7.35.556 Minecraft Forge 6.6.2.534 Feed The Beast Mod Pack 91 mods loaded, 91 mods active
    mcp [Minecraft Coder Pack] (minecraft.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    FML [Forge Mod Loader] (coremods) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    Forge [Minecraft Forge] (coremods) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    CodeChickenCore [CodeChicken Core] (coremods) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    MiscPeripheralsASM [MiscPeripherals ASM] (coremods) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    NotEnoughItems [Not Enough Items] (coremods) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    PowerCrystalsCore [PowerCrystals Core] (coremods) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    ComputerCraft [ComputerCraft] (computercraft.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    CCTurtle [ComputerCraft Turtles] (computercraft.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    BuildCraft|Core [BuildCraft] (buildcraft.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    BuildCraft|Builders [BC Builders] (buildcraft.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    BuildCraft|Energy [BC Energy] (buildcraft.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    BuildCraft|Factory [BC Factory] (buildcraft.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    BuildCraft|Transport [BC Transport] (buildcraft.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    BuildCraft|Silicon [BC Silicon] (buildcraft.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    factorization [Factorization] (factorization.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    ExtrabiomesXL [ExtrabiomesXL] (extrabiomes.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    Forestry [Forestry for Minecraft] (forestry.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    CoFHCore [CoFH Core] (CoFHCore.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    ThermalExpansion [Thermal Expansion] (thermalexpansion.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    OmniTools [OmniTools] (omnitools.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    IC2 [IndustrialCraft 2] (IC2.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    Railcraft [Railcraft] (railcraft.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    RedPowerCore [RedPower] (redpowercore.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    RedPowerBase [RP Base] (redpowercore.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    RedPowerMachine [RP Machine] (redpowermechanical.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    RedPowerCompat [RP Compat] (redpowercompat.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    RedPowerWiring [RP Wiring] (redpowerdigital.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    RedPowerLogic [RP Logic] (redpowerdigital.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    RedPowerLighting [RP Lighting] (redpowerdigital.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    RedPowerWorld [RP World] (redpowermechanical.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    RedPowerControl [RP Control] (redpowermechanical.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    ThermalExpansion|Factory [Factory] (thermalexpansion.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    ThermalExpansion|Energy [Energy] (thermalexpansion.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    ThermalExpansion|Transport [Transport] (thermalexpansion.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    ImmibisCore [Immibis Core] (immibiscore.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    Tubestuff [Tubestuff] (tubestuff.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    TwilightForest [The Twilight Forest] (TwilightForest.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    XyCraft [§3XyCraft] (xycraft.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    GregTech_Addon [GregTech-Addon] (GregTech.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    MiscPeripherals [MiscPeripherals] (MiscPeripherals.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    AdvancedMachines [IC2 Advanced Machines Addon] (advancedmachines.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    AdvancedSolarPanel [Advanced Solar Panels] (advancedsolarpanel.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    AppliedEnergistics [Applied Energistics] (AppliedEnergistics.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    BetterDungeons [Better dungeons] (BetterDungeons.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Errored
    BiblioCraft [BiblioCraft] (BiblioCraft.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    ChargePads [Charge Pads] (ChargePads.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    ChickenChunks [ChickenChunks] (ChickenChunks.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    EE3 [Equivalent Exchange 3] (ee3.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    EnderStorage [EnderStorage] (EnderStorage.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    BinnieCore [Binnie Core] (extrabees.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    ExtraBees [Extra Bees] (extrabees.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    FlatBedrock [FlatBedrock] (FlatBedrock.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    ForgeIRC [ForgeIRC] (forgeirc.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    GraviGun [GraviGun] (GraviGun.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    GraviSuite [Gravitation Suite] (gravisuite.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    IC2NuclearControl [Nuclear Control] (IC2NuclearControl.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    mod_InvTweaks [Inventory Tweaks] (InvTweaks.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    IronChest [Iron Chest] (IronChest.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    MFReloaded [Minefactory Reloaded] (MineFactoryReloaded.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    MFReloaded|CompatExtraBiomes [MFR Compat: ExtraBiomes] (MineFactoryReloaded.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    MFReloaded|CompatForestry [MFR Compat: Forestry] (MineFactoryReloaded.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    MFReloaded|CompatIC2 [MFR Compat: IC2] (MineFactoryReloaded.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    MFReloaded|CompatPams [MFR Compat: Pam's Mods] (MineFactoryReloaded.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    MFReloaded|CompatRP2 [MFR Compat: RP2] (MineFactoryReloaded.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    SoulShards [SoulShards] (soulshards.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    MFReloaded|CompatSoulShards [MFR Compat: Soul Shards] (MineFactoryReloaded.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    MFReloaded|CompatSufficientBiomes [MFR Compat: Sufficient Biomes] (MineFactoryReloaded.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    Thaumcraft [Thaumcraft] (Thaumcraft.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    MFReloaded|CompatThaumcraft [MFR Compat: Thaumcraft] (MineFactoryReloaded.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    MFReloaded|CompatTwilightForest [MFR Compat: TwilightForest] (MineFactoryReloaded.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    XyCraftWorld [§2XyCraft World] (xycraft.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    MFReloaded|CompatXycraft [MFR Compat: Xycraft] (MineFactoryReloaded.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    ModularForceFieldSystem [Modular ForceField System V2] (modularforcefieldsystem.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    mmmPowersuits [MachineMuse's Modular Powersuits] (ModularPowersuits.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    Mystcraft [Mystcraft] (mystcraft.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    NEIPlugins [NEI Plugins] (neiplugins.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    NetherOres [Nether Ores] (NetherOres.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    ObsidiPlates [Obsidian Pressure Plates] (obsidiplates.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    drceph.petrogen [Petroleum Generator] (petrogen.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    PortalGun [Portal Gun] (PortalGun.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    PowerConverters [Power Converters] (PowerConverters.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    SecretRoomsMod [The SecretRoomsMod] (secretroomsmod.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    StevesCarts [Steve's Carts] (StevesCarts.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    ThaumicBees [ThaumicBees] (ThaumicBees.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    WR-CBE|Core [WR-CBE Core] (wirelessredstonecore.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    WR-CBE|Addons [WR-CBE Addons] (wirelessredstoneaddons.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    WR-CBE|RedPower [WR-CBE RedPower] (wirelessredstoneredpower.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    XReliquary [Xeno's Reliquary] (XReliquary.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    XyCraftMachines [§9XyCraft Machines] (xycraft.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    NEI-Mystcraft-Plugin [NEI Mystcraft Plugin] (neipluginMyst.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized
    LWJGL: 2.4.2
    OpenGL: AMD Radeon HD 6900 Series GL version 4.2.12002 Compatibility Profile Context 9.12.0.0, ATI Technologies Inc.
    Is Modded: Definitely; Client brand changed to 'forge,fml'
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    Texture Pack: Soartex.zip
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
    Vec3 Pool Size: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null ##
```

Googled how to do it but I can't find anything that deals with Better Dungeons specifically and i've even used edit mod pack from the FTB laucher.

Comment: (Using "edit mod pack" in the FTB launcher also won't work for Better Dungeons because the zip file's internal structure is not standard.)

Comment: Although I think this is a good question with a good, useful answer, it is a modded minecraft crash, which is categorically off-topic, and off-topic rules apply regardless of the quality of the question and answer. Hence, I am flagging it for closure.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because tech support for modded Minecraft is off-topic here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The crash report explains itself right at the top:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Slot 250 is already occupied by forestry.apiculture.gadgets.BlockBeehives@1a37a86e when adding chocolate.mods.BD.BlockMobSpawner@70aa8b52
```

Better Dungeons is trying to use the same block ID for its new mob spawner blocks as the wild beehives in Forestry. You have to fix that.

Unfortunately, Better Dungeons is one of those rare Forge mods that doesn't use a config file to assign its block IDs, which means the easy way of fixing this is not available to you, and that's something the author should fix. (Consider posting in the BD thread and requesting that block IDs be changeable in the config file for the 1.4.7 and later versions.)

You can reassign the block ID for Forestry beehives instead. However, be aware that some mods require their block IDs to be sequential, so changing a block ID for a big mod might force you to change *many* block IDs, or at least any that form a sequence of numbers. Fortunately for the case of the beehive, it's not part of a sequence of block IDs so it's safe to change. The other drawback of doing it this way is that it will make your new configuration incompatible with any existing worlds you've started, but if you're installing Better Dungeons, you're probably starting over in a new world anyway so you can get the new structures everywhere.

Note that Minecraft will crash as soon as it finds the first block conflict. Once you've fixed the beehive/spawner conflict, you'll probably see it crash again on another block conflict. You'll just keep doing this, fixing one conflict at a time, until it runs without that crash message.

As a semi-automated alternative, you might want to install the [ID Resolver mod](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/366377-146id-resolver-now-supports-smp-sort-of/). It'll detect block conflicts and ask you what to do with them. It has buttons to assign the conflicting block to a new ID automatically, as well as a button to automatically reassign all IDs for a mod to new numbers. Note that this might not work for Better Dungeons, though – if it's not already using a config file for block IDs, it might have other coding errors that make it crash if the block IDs are changed. If that's the case, you'll be better off not using the resolver mod and just editing the other mods' config files by hand.

Comment: It's specifically the beehive (the ones in world generation, id 250) that's causing the conflict, but I'm sure there's others too.

Comment: @RonanForman Right, thanks. That there will likely be more conflicts and crashes isn't intuitive, so I should explain in more detail how clearing ID conflicts is done.

Comment: can you be a bit more descriptive on how to change the block ID, my knowledge of config files is pretty limited.

Comment: I cant seem to figure out how to change the block ID.

Comment: @Paralytic If you've found and opened the config file, it should have a section that's just a list of names and numbers. Change the one for mob spawners to a number that another mod isn't using. Trial and error, or browsing through *all* the other mods' config files, are the only ways to find free block IDs.

Comment: attempted to disable forestry, FTB won't let me haha

Comment: that's what i thought but i can't find anything in the config file that says mob or spawner or 250. i've gotta be doing something wrong.

Comment: @Paralytic I see what you mean. Better Dungeons is one of those Forge mods that doesn't assign block IDs with a config file, which means it's just badly written. You could try reassigning Forestry's block IDs instead.

Comment: I found the block spawner in the .zip file just don't know what to change to change the block ID, i tried something but it gave me a different error message after crashing.

Comment: figured it out, gonna add an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Alright before I answer this I wanna give 99% credit to SevenSidedDie as without him I wouldn't have been able to figure this out, although it did take some time to find this and the litte trial and error I did.

First Download BetterDungeons. Make sure you have WinRAR or a similar program that extracts files.

Go into your FTB folder, click on the modpack you loaded, for example I loaded the Ultimate Modpack so I clicked on the "Ultimate" Folder. Then click the "Minecraft" Folder. Here is where you will open the BetterDungeons file you loaded with WinRAR (or similar program). The first folder you will see is the folder titled "Copy the contents in this folder into your .minecraft folder", ignore the title as it does not apply, click on it. proceed to copy and paste the "Chocolate" folder into the "Minecraft" folder you should have previously opened. Now go back to the BetterDungeons folder, click on the "Mods" folder and copy and paste the "BetterDungeons.zip" file into your "Minecraft/mods" folder. Now that you have completed this launch your FTB Launcher, then launch your modpack.

Minecraft will crash, at this point close out of minecraft and go pack to your FTB Folder. Click on your Modpack folder just like before. Then click on the "Minecraft" folder. Proceed to the "Chocolate" folder. There should be a PROP File there now named "config" click on it and open it with Notepad. You should be able to see some text "blockID = 250" change this to "blockID = 1206". save the file and close out and launch your game it should now work.

[image]

wow that picture is awful...

Comment: Ahah! They just put the config file in a weird, non-standard place. Good to know!